# search query to exclude microfeed with guid list items

Tags: search, 2016

I am querying on the Microfeed list to show the feed conversation. When I run the query, it shows GUID (as in the list item) but I need to show the feeds itself?

What's query rule should be used to exclude the microfeed list items from search result without affecting the feed conversation itself?

Any thoughts please!